React native integrated sentry reports an error when compiling and packaging on ios
react native 0.65.1
sentry 5.35.0
error message:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe", referenced from:
      function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of function signature specialization <Arg[0] = [Closure Propagated : closure #1 ((key: Swift.String, value: Swift.String)) -> Swift.Bool in static Sentry.HTTPHeaderSanitizer.sanitizeHeaders(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>) -> Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>, Argument Types : [Swift.Set<Swift.String>]> of generic specialization <Swift.String, Swift.String> of Swift._NativeDictionary.filter(((key: A, value: B)) throws -> Swift.Bool) throws -> Swift._NativeDictionary<A, B> in libSentry.a[251](HTTPHeaderSanitizer.o)
      function signature specialization <Arg[0] = [Closure Propagated : closure #1 ((key: Swift.String, value: Any)) -> Swift.Bool in Sentry.SentrySRDefaultBreadcrumbConverter.convert(from: __C.SentryBreadcrumb) -> Swift.Optional<Sentry.SentryRRWebEventProtocol>, Argument Types : []> of generic specialization <Swift.String, Any> of Swift._NativeDictionary.filter(((key: A, value: B)) throws -> Swift.Bool) throws -> Swift._NativeDictionary<A, B> in libSentry.a[290](SentrySRDefaultBreadcrumbConverter.o)
      function signature specialization <Arg[0] = [Closure Propagated : closure #1 ((key: __C.UITouch, value: Sentry.SentryTouchTracker.(TouchInfo in _D7F038D1679999BD19B9314352D13E97))) -> Swift.Bool in Sentry.SentryTouchTracker.flushFinishedEvents() -> (), Argument Types : []> of generic specialization <__C.UITouch, Sentry.SentryTouchTracker.(TouchInfo in _D7F038D1679999BD19B9314352D13E97)> of Swift._NativeDictionary.filter(((key: A, value: B)) throws -> Swift.Bool) throws -> Swift._NativeDictionary<A, B> in libSentry.a[291](SentryTouchTracker.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried adding the following code to the podfile, but the same error message still appears.
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
  end
end

